# Need help in understanding variables with Operator overloading in python

Tags: python

need help in understanding the variables in the below code.

```
class Student:
def __init__(self,m1,m2):
    self.m1 = m1
    self.m2 = m2
def __add__(self, other):
    m1 = self.m1 + self.m2 <---- doubt
    m2 = other.m2 + other.m2
    s3 = Student(m1,m2)
    return s3


s1 = Student(50,60)
s2 = Student(70,80)

s3 = s1 + s2
print (s3.m1)
```

So i get the desired output of 110 here. But my question is why should the variable in add function be declared only as m1 and not as any other variable. Does it have to match with the variable name in "init" function? If yes what is the reason for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, do you mean whether this could have worked:
`anything = self.m1 + self.m2`
etc
?

Comment: Yeah!!. Why is it that only m1 = self.m1 + self.m2 works but a1 = self.m1 + self.m2 gives me an error?

Comment: @BhargavMg Are you sure? Please send the issue code, and the error you get.

Comment: Please find the below code.

Comment: "`m1 = self.m1 + self.m2` works but `a1 = self.m1 + self.m2` gives me an error" is only possible if you forgot to change all references of `m1` into `a1`, e.g. `Student(m1,m2)` to `Student(a1,m2)`.

Comment: class Student:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2
    def __add__(self, other):
        a1 = self.m1 + self.m2
        a2 = other.m2 + other.m2
        a3 = Student(a1,a2)
        return a3

    s1 = Student(50,60)
    s2 = Student(70,80)

    s3 = s1 + s2
    print (s3.a1)
    print (s3.a1)
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'a1'

Comment: 1) Put that code into the question, not a comment. 2) Why do you think `s3` has an `a1` when you didn't save it anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

the name doesn't matter, it is just convention to make it more readable, this should work just as well:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    a1 = self.m1 + self.m2 
    m2 = other.m2 + other.m2
    s3 = Student(a1,m2)
    return s3
```

do pay attention that you have to modify `m1` twice (but leave them untouched in `self` and `other`)

edit: there appears to be some mistake in the code, as `m2` appears 3 times and `m1` appears only once

Comment: Hello please find the below code.
 
    class Student:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2
    def __add__(self, other):
        a1 = self.m1 + self.m2
        a2 = other.m2 + other.m2
        a3 = Student(a1,a2)
        return a3

    s1 = Student(50,60)
    s2 = Student(70,80)

    s3 = s1 + s2
    print (s3.a1)

        print (s3.a1)
    AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'a1'

Comment: Ok, if that is what you mean, then yes, the names of class members are defined in the `__init__`, and they cannot be changed. `a1` and `a2` were only temporary variables stored during `__add__` and then trashed when it is done running

Comment: Got it. Thank you:)